# C# gRPC service without proto file

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I'm looking for a way to communicate between different C# (only) apps via gRPC. Is there any way to provide service definitions and contracts by C# interfaces and POCO classes (attributed by ProtoMember, etc.), instead of creating a proto file and generating a code out of it? I need this to work on .net framework 4.7.2, i.e. working with grpc.core rather than grpc.dotnet.

PS: The main idea why I want this is to avoid the code generation part which seems to be excessive here. Also need to be able to specify custom attributes to my POCO classes, like DisplayAttribute and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, looks like I found the answer https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/issues/68
protobuf-net.Grpc seems like the lib I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [ServiceStack gRPC](https://docs.servicestack.net/grpc) which provides code-first development.

Comment: Be aware that ServiceStack is not open source.